# Relationship between a closed operator and an operator with dense image.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $T: X \to Y$ be a linear map. We say that $T$ is $\textbf{closed}$ if $x_n \to x$ and $Tx_n \to y$ implies that $y=Tx$. 
Loosely speaking, (hopefully not incorrectly speaking), the closeness of an operator is a weaker condition than continuity.

Suppose now that the image of $T$ in $Y$ is dense. Is there a relationship between this and the closeness of the operator?

i.e, does $T$ having dense image in $Y$ imply that $T$ is closed?

Comment: Of course, you assume that there is some kind of topology on $X$, respectively $Y$.

Comment: Sure we assume there is a topology on the respective space. I am not entirely sure how to prove an operator is closed, and thus not sure how to show it is implied by density. It would be nice to see a proof (or just a sketch of the proof).

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is **no**. You can take any non-closed operator $T$ and restrict its codomain to the closure of $\text{ran}\,(T)$. The image of this new operator is dense, and it is easy to verify (according to your definition) that it remains non-closed.